# Assign on declaration or assign in the constrctor?

Tags: java, constructor

is there a diffrence between this :

```
public class A {
    B b;
    A() {
        b=new B();
    }
}
```

and this :

```
public class A {
    B b=new B();
    A() {
    }
}
```

if there is, what is it? and what is better practice?
if there is no, whats recommanded?

Comment: I'd go with the second option. It makes it pretty clear what the intention is (the field `b` will always refer to an instance of the class `B` when the class is initialised), and means you don't have to do it in every single constructor (assuming you're declaring more than one for the class).

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know there is no difference as long as you only have one constructor. If you have more than one constructor you will need to make sure it's assigned in all constructors. For that reason i would recommend  the second approach.

Comment: I assume you actually meant the second approach? Otherwise your answer seems slightly contradictory.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor runs after the instance variables are initialized, so there is a difference.  It doesn't matter in a small example, but it can matter with more complex code.  (Note, the order of the code doesn't matter.  If the initialization is in the constructor, it runs second.)

The second approach is more convenient, so I tend to start with it.  The first approach can be more useful though (for Inversion of Control and Polymorphism), so it often gets used in "real" code.

```
class B {
    B() {
        System.out.println("B constructor");
    }
}

public class A {
    B b=new B();

    A() {
        System.out.println("A constructor");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
B constructor
A constructor
```

....

```
class B {
    B() {
        System.out.println("B constructor");
    }
}

public class A {
    B b;
    A() {
        System.out.println("A constructor");
        b=new B();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A constructor
B constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

Big Difference between them.

In first option Class B only instantiate when constructor without parameter is called. If you put and call any parametrized constructor  Class B will not instantiate.

But in case of second option Class B will always instantiate regardless of any constructor call.